# Android Facebook integration exception

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

I'm doing Android Facebook integration tutorial its giving me this exception.

I have added library perfectly then also its giving this exception.

```
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301): Process: com.tag.facebooksharingdemo, PID: 18301
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.tag.facebooksharingdemo/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.facebook.platform.PLATFORM_SERVICE cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] }
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2993)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3028)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5310)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.facebook.platform.PLATFORM_SERVICE cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] }
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:1808)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1907)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1885)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:538)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at com.facebook.GetTokenClient.start(GetTokenClient.java:62)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$GetTokenAuthHandler.tryAuthorize(AuthorizationClient.java:505)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryCurrentHandler(AuthorizationClient.java:209)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryNextHandler(AuthorizationClient.java:188)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.authorize(AuthorizationClient.java:116)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.startOrContinueAuth(AuthorizationClient.java:97)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at com.facebook.LoginActivity.onResume(LoginActivity.java:113)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1264)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6039)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2976)
10-26 21:26:00.653: E/AndroidRuntime(18301):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please link the tutorial you're following and include the code that broke.

Comment: http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-facebook-integration-tutorial this is the link